# How to mark a place in a levelplot raster?

Tags: r, raster

I have a raster file that i want show the places of the sites I used in this map. I wonder if you have help here:

```
 library(rasterVis)
 r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
 r[] = 1
 r[51:100] = 3
 r[3:6, 1:5] = 5
 r <- ratify(r)
 rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
 rat$landcover <- c('Pine', 'Oak', 'Meadow')
 rat$class <- c('A1', 'B2', 'C3')
 levels(r) <- rat
 levelplot(r, col.regions=c('palegreen', 'midnightblue', 'indianred1'))
```

I want to show the place where lat = 50 and long=100. just to put a circle or square in this point on the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will add a single point at lat=50, lon=100:

```
levelplot(r, col.regions=c('palegreen', 'midnightblue', 'indianred1')) +
  layer(panel.points(100,50, pch=21, cex=3, colour='black', fill='red'))
```

`pch` sets the marker type (see `?pch` for the various marker types), `cex` controls the size.

[image]